# Error when using visual keras for plotting model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visualization

I'm trying to visualize my Deep Learning model using visual keras, but i am getting an error which i am not sure i understand. This is my first time using visual keras, and i am not sure what to do. As an example

```
!pip install visual keras 

import visualkeras
import tensorflow as tf 

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='input')
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(output_dim=512, input_dim=10000, input_length=100)(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
visualkeras.layered_view(model, legend=True, draw_volume=False)
```

and the error looks like this `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug as you can read [here](https://github.com/paulgavrikov/visualkeras/issues/15). The author suggests to install a newer version of the library:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/paulgavrikov/visualkeras --upgrade
```

If for some reason you cannot update the version. Go to the source code of the library (where it was installed) and navigate to `visualkeras/layered.py`. In line 100 of this file, change `z = min(max(z), max_z)` to `z = min(max([z]), max_z)`. Save the changes and it will work. An example:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/paulgavrikov/visualkeras --upgrade
import visualkeras
import tensorflow as tf 

input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='input')
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(output_dim=512, input_dim=10000, input_length=100)(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
visualkeras.layered_view(model, legend=True, draw_volume=False)
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried it, and no it does not work still. Getting the same error.

Comment: @OliveYew did you run the example ?